# Appengine + Bigquery = 403 Access Denied

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, webapp2

I'm trying connect my GCP projects appengine application to Bigquery and I'm facing issues with access (Forbidden 403).

I'm following the reference provided here: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

I'm getting an error:

```
Project sample-1423: The user sample-1423@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project sample-1423
```

1. The default appengine service account (sample-1423@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) has editor role set.
2. This error occurs on appengine and local with same error, I've set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDETIALS env variable to a key linked to the service account.
3. From the below link it seems I dont have to do anything if I'm running on appengine.
   https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application

**Code:**

```
user = users.get_current_user()
  client = bigquery.Client()
  auth_query = AUTH_QUERY
  params = (bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('email', 'STRING', user.email()),)
  auth_job = client.run_async_query(
      str(uuid.uuid4()), auth_query, query_parameters=params)
  auth_job.use_legacy_sql = False
  auth_job.begin()
  auth_job.result()
  table = auth_job.destination
  table.reload()
```

**Error:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Users/user/projects/sample/main.py", line 43, in dispatch
    if not user_in_system():
  File "/Users/user/projects/sample/main.py", line 30, in user_in_system
    auth_job.begin()
  File "/Users/user/projects/sample/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 373, in begin
    method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
  File "/Users/user/projects/sample/lib/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/sample-1432/jobs: Access Denied: Project sample-1432: The user sample-1432@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project sample-1432.
```

Comment: Odd. Having Editor role should be more than enough. Can you test what happens when you add a finer grained BigQuery IAM? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Comment: Tried giving more granular permissions got same result 403. Think I should go apidiscover route.

Comment: Really strange. Sorry, I'm stumped. Hopefully a Googler can help. They are much smarter than me.

Comment: Used to have the same error with NodeJS, had to create a service account then give him access right in the IAM and use a credential key generate from IAM too.